# sed: replace a certain pattern with an arbitrary string in between

Tags: script, sed

I'm trying to clean up a log file for better readability - there's a load of un-necessary stuff there to my needs - i basically have to replace sshd[xxxx] where xxxx is an arbitrary number with, well, either a space or nothing. While i can replace a known string, i have no idea how to do a sed wildcard in this case- So- how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not clear whether you want the replace the "sshd" as well, so i assumed you it is.

```
   sed 's/sshd\[[0-9]*\]//g' file
```

otherwise,

```
   sed 's/sshd\[[0-9]*\]/sshd[]/g' file
```

Comment: the first one was what i was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to replace *all* numbers after `sshd` inside `[]` with nothing. To select numbers you can use a range `[0-9]\+`, where `[0-9]` matches any digit and `\+` means *one or more of that before*.

So for your case the regexp to replace numbers with zeros would be

```
sed -r s/\[[0-9]\+\]/\[\]/
```

where the `-r` enables extended regexp's like the one above. The `\[` and `\]` are just to escape the `[` and `]` so they don't get interpreted by `sed`.

For regexp operators like `\+` have a look at [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators) in the `gawk` manual, for character list like `[0-9]` see [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Character-Lists.html#Character-Lists) -- most of what you see there applies to `sed` as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be `sed -r s/\[[0-9]\+\]/\[\]/`, in order to keep the [] without the number?

Comment: @snark you're right

Comment: You can omit the `-r` if you quote the command. If you do both (use `-r` and quote the command), you can omit the escaping of the +. `sed 's/\[[0-9]\+\]/\[\]/'` or `sed -r 's/\[[0-9]+\]/\[\]/'` Often, when there are grouping parentheses, using `-r` with quoting can save several characters and improve readability since the parentheses don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Dennis interesting